# How to auto start subversion server on boot in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: svn, systemd, ubuntu-20.04, autostart

I'm trying to decom my old svn server and I can't get svn to auto start on boot in Ubuntu 20.04. I feel like I have read 100 blogs and help posts, but I can't get it to work.

The end result when I try to "systemctl enable svnserve.service" I get the error:

update-rc.d: error: svnserve Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.

Here is exactly what I have put into place. I have tried it using a shell script and calling it directly with $DAEMON_ARGS. Neither will work.

Create a systemd service file

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service
```

Copy the following into the file

```
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
#ExecStart=svnserve -d -r /var/lib/svn
#ExecStart==/etc/default/svnserve $DAEMON_ARGS
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start_svn.sh

[Install]
#WantedBy=default.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Set permissions

```
chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service
```

Create the following file

```
nano /etc/default/svnserve
```

Add the following to the file

```
# svnserve options
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemon --pid-file /run/svnserve/svnserve.pid --root /var/lib/svn"
```

Create the script file

```
nano /usr/local/bin/start_svn.sh
```

Add the following to the file

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          svnserve.service
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Starts SVN Server
### END INIT INFO
svnserve -d -r /var/lib/svn
```

Make it executable

```
chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/start_svn.sh
```

Enable the service unit

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start svnserve.service
systemctl enable svnserve.service
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

After running systemctl status svnserve.service

svnserve.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

On another note, I copied the process in this post: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-server-desktop

I got that script working with no issues. I then added:

svnserve -d -r /var/lib/svn

to the shell script. On reboot, the script runs and updates the drive space but SVN will still not start. I've looked at some journal entries but I'm not finding anything. Does not make sense why it will not start on boot. If I run the shell script manually once logged in, it does work.

Comment: Why not directly call `svnserve -d -r /var/lib/svn` without the script? With the script runtime detection and service stop is more complicated. Have you verified that svnserve starts when you execute it from command-line? What does `systemctl status svnserve.service` output?

Comment: @Robert - I actually started out with adding it directly and it didn't work, I edited my post to reflect that now. While testing that once more, I also realized I had a typo in my sveserve.service file pointing to the wrong location of the svnserve, I fixed that but still didn't work. Good suggestion on the status output. The status has some interesting things. I'm going to work through these and comment later of what I find.

Comment: @Robert - ExecStart=svnserve -d -r /var/lib/svn Status Output: 
svnserve.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 10 13:52:13 ICESVN-01 systemd[1]: Started svnserve.service.
Oct 10 13:52:13 ICESVN-01 svnserve[1320]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Oct 10 13:52:13 ICESVN-01 systemd[1]: svnserve.service: Succeeded.

Running 'netstat -tulpn| grep' svn shows nothing

Comment: ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start_svn.sh Status Output: 
 svnserve.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/svnserve.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 10 14:21:50 ICESVN-01 systemd[1]: Started svnserve.service.
Oct 10 14:21:51 ICESVN-01 svnserve[1310]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Oct 10 14:21:51 ICESVN-01 systemd[1]: svnserve.service: Succeeded.
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start_svn.sh

Running 'netstat -tulpn| grep' svn shows nothing

Comment: @Robert - Copy that. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/svnserve -d --foreground -r /var/lib/svn

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Service is active (running) and listening on port 3690. OS Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Please share your `/usr/local/bin/start_svn.sh`

The initial best practice guidelines are:

1. Specify full absolute path to each command. A command with relative/implicit path will fail.
2. Load all environment variable at script beginning with absolute full path.
3. Use explicit log file to debug each important line in the script.

Comment: The contents of that file are in my original post above. Just under where it says "Add the following to the file."

Comment: Try to find the absolute path to `svnserve`, use Linux command `which svnserve` to find out. Update your  `/usr/local/bin/start_svn.sh` accordingly.

Comment: Also if you do not specify user/group in service unit. The default user is `root`.

Comment: I confirmed the location of svnserve with which at /usr/bin/svnserve. I updated the start_svn.sh file with that full path. Still does not work. I'm wondering if specifying the user/group would help. I did a standard install and named my user differently but that is all. The svnserve file seems to have the correct permissions:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 112936 Mar 24  2020 svnserve*